# jquery selector to find a child element with

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, find

Have been googling and trial-and-erroring for an hour trying to come up with a jquery selector to access one of several label elements in an expandable tree. The html is either like this:

```
<span id="ppown" class="treeTitleSpan" role="leaf">PPO</span> 
<span class="treeCheckBoxLabel"> 
    <label class='nodeCheckIcon'  />
```

Or like this:

```
<span id="ppw" class="treeTitleSpan" role="leaf">Other</span> 
<span class="handle closed"></span>
<span class="treeCheckBoxLabel"> 
    <label class='nodeCheckIcon'  />
```

And I am starting from the .treeTitleSpan span in each case (in a click handler). I know I can access one with:

```
$(this).next().next().children('.nodeCheckIcon');
```

And the other with:

```
$(this).next().children('.nodeCheckIcon');
```

But I would like a single selector that will work for both cases, 'find' doesn't seem to work:

```
$(this).find('.nodeCheckIcon:first')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

rick

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).nextAll('.treeCheckBoxLabel').children('.nodeCheckIcon');
```

Or if you might have more than one Label like:

```
<span id="ppw" class="treeTitleSpan" role="leaf">Other</span> 
<span class="handle closed"></span>
<span class="treeCheckBoxLabel"> 
    <label class='nodeCheckIcon'  />
</span>
<span class="treeCheckBoxLabel"> 
    <label class='nodeCheckIcon'  />
</span>
```

And you only want the first one:

```
$(this).nextAll('.treeCheckBoxLabel').first().children('.nodeCheckIcon');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
$(this).nextAll('.treeCheckBoxLabel:first').children('.nodeCheckIcon');
```

Using `:first` ensures you'll only select one `.treeCheckBoxLabel` at most, which may or may not be an issue depending on the rest of your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to the other posts (many ways to skin a cat :))

```
$(this).siblings(".treeCheckBoxLabel:has(label.nodeCheckIcon):first")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `this` is pointing to the `span` element which is the sibling of the parent of `label`, `$(this).find('.nodeCheckIcon:first')` is not going to work. I dont know about your complete markup structure, but if you have a wrapping container for this span element then you can try this

```
$(this).parent().find('.nodeCheckIcon:first');
```